# User Profile Property

Tags: powershell, user-profile

In share point i have defined a custom property  and in central admin it is showing that 414 users are using this property is there any way that i can get the details of the user using that property

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use some powershell like

```
$url = "http://sp2010/"
$site = Get-SPSite $url
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
$profiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator()

while ($profiles.MoveNext()) {
  $userProfile = $profiles.Current
  $name = $userProfile.DisplayName
  $yourProp = $userProfile["YourPropName"]
  Write-Host "$name;$yourProp"
}
```

Comment: +1 just when I was about to submit my code, you posted yours :)